# an empty pdf created when a figure with subplots was saved as pdf from matpolotlib in python3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I need to save a figure (with 8 subplots on it) generated from matpolotlib in python3.2. I need to same save the figure on **one** pdf page.
**Each subplot nmay have 240k to 400k data points.**

My code:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
plt.show(block=False)
pp = PdfPages('multipage.pdf')
fig = plt.figure()
fig.savefig('figure_1.pdf', dpi = fig.dpi)
pp.close()
```

But, only an empty pdf file was created and no figures on it. 
Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
This is a demo code:

```
def plot_pdf_example():

    fig = plt.figure() 

    # I create subplots here 
    #x = np.random.rand(50)
    #y = np.random.rand(50)

    plt.plot(x, y, '.')

    fig.savefig('figure_b.pdf')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = plot_pdf_example()
    # the return value of r is not 0 for my case
    print("donne")
```

If I used plt.show() to get the figure in pop-up window, there are some titles and legends overlaps between subplots. How to adjuse the pop-up figure so that I can get all subplots without any overlaps and also keep all subplots as square. **keeping them as square uis very important for me.**

Comment: If you want help on how to place your subplots correctly, I think you should start a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does save the single and empty figure `fig` to the file `figure_1.pdf`, without making any use of `PdfPages`. It is also normal that the pdf file is empty, since you are not plotting anything in `fig`. Below is a MWE that shows how to save only one figure to a single pdf file. I've removed all the stuff with `PdfPages` that was not necessary.

**Update (2015-07-27):** When there is some problem saving a fig to pdf because there is too much data to render or in the cases of complex and detailed colormaps, it may be a good idea to rasterize some of the elements of the plot that are problematic. The MWE below has been updated to reflect that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time

plt.close("all")

fig = plt.figure()

N = 400000   
x = np.random.rand(400000)
y = np.random.rand(400000)
colors = np.random.rand(400000)
area = 3

ax0 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.85, 0.85])

scater = ax0.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors)
scater.set_rasterized(True)

plt.show(block=False)

ts = time.clock()
fig.savefig('figure_1.pdf')
te = time.clock()

print('t = %f sec' % (te-ts))
```

On my machine, the code above took about 6.5 sec to save the pdf when rasterized was set to true for `scater`, while it took 61.5 sec when it was set to False.

By default, when saving in pdf, the figure is saved in [vectorial format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics). This means that every point is saved as a set of parameters (colors, size, position, etc). This is a lot of information to store when there is a lot of data (8 * 400k in the case of the OP). When converting some elements of the plot to a [raster format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics), the number of points plotted does not matter because the image is saved as a fixed number of pixels instead (like in a png). By only rasterizing the `scater`, the rest of the figure (axes, labels, text, legend, etc.) still remains in vectorial format. So overall, the loss in quality is not that much noticeable for some type of graph (like colormaps or scatter plots), but it will be for graphs with sharp lines.

Comment: I need to same save the figure on one pdf page.

Comment: @user3601704 i've update my answer to take into account your comment.

Comment: your example works but for my case, I have 8 subplots in one figure, it took a long time to create the pdf file. 10 minutes has past but still not finished. Are there other ways to create the pdf files ?

Comment: @user3601704 It is hard to tell like that why it's taking so long without knowing more information about what you are doing exactly. But the 8 subplots should not be a problem, unless you are plotting a lot of datapoints or colormaps. What happen if you do `fig.savefig('figure_1.png', dpi=96)` for example. Post the results in your OP so we can see what you are actually plotting.

Comment: @user3601704 Also, does the same behaviour also occurs when you save from the popup window when you do `plt.show()`?

Comment: my subplots have 240k to 400k data points, all of them are green colored. This may be a reason for the slow ?

Comment: when I saved the figure from the popup window, the result pdf has subplots' titles and legends overlapped.

Comment: @user3601704 This is a lot of data to plot... If possible, I suggest you rasterize some elements of your plot before saving to pdf (see updated answer). As for the overlapping problem, it is not a good practice to mixed up different questions in a single post. I suggest you start a new question for this particular issue.

Comment: it works, thanks ! set_rasterized can really save time, why ?

Comment: @user3601704 This is because in vectorial format, every point is saved as a set of parameters (colors, size, position, etc). This is a lot of information to store when there is a lot of data (8 * 400k). When rasterizing, the number of points plotted does not matter because the image is saved as a fixed number of pixels instead (like in a png). By only rasterizing the `scater`, the rest of the figure (axes, labels, etc.) still remain in vectorial format. So overall, the loss in quality is not that much noticeable for some type of graph (like colormaps.).